# Removing duplicate lines from text file

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I'm trying to remove all duplicate lines from a file and using this command:

```
sort text.txt | uniq -u > ALL.txt
```

But am getting this error:

```
sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were `http://lestarsmagazine.com/2011/10/07/adja-ndoye-ex-mannequin-\253-balla-gaye-adja-diallo-mara-ndiaye-l\222alcool-la-drogue-et-moi-\273/2691278-3806038/ | 0\r' and `http://sopfree.com/slight-conditioning/ | 0\r'.
```

What do I need to change the command to in order to work around this problem?

Comment: Note that `uniq -u` will just show lines appearing once. So if a line appears >=2 times, it will not be shown *at all*.

Answer (score 3):

```
LC_ALL='C' sort text.txt | LC_ALL='C' uniq > ALL.txt
```

Edit: Removed the '-u'. From your description it sounds like you shouldn't be using it. You may have misunderstood the man page. That option will skip non-unique lines from the input rather than merging them.

Comment: That should work. If it's not I would probably need your original input file to figure out why. If you're able you can share it on http://www.filedropper.com.

Comment: I added a second `LC_ALL='C'`, which would resolve the error from being thrown by `uniq` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that your command is incorrect, but rather your data. From the error, it looks like the line separators in `text.txt` are incorrect or mangled. I'd strongly suggest you review your data (even just opening it in a text editor and saving it back out again may fix it) or post it here so someone else can review it.